# Django: SSL + trailing slash cause URL in browser to show unusual path

Tags: python, django

Hosting: A2Hosting
Reference for A2Hosting deploy: [link](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/python/installing-and-configuring-django-on-linux-shared-hosting)
Python: 3.8.1
Django: 3.1.1
Webserver: Apache

When "SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = **False**" in *settings.py*, having the trailing slash in the *urls.py* paths causes no issue.

```
    urlpatterns = [
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
       path('login/', dashboard, name="dashboard"),
   ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
   urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

In fact, accessing the URL http://subdomain.domain.com/login (or admin) the correct page is shown.

But when I set "SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = **True**", if I maintain the trailing slash and I access the same URLs, the page is still correctly shown, but the URL in the browser address bar changes.

Instead to be:
https://subdomain.domain.com/login
it becomes:
https://subdomain.domain.com/home/user/a2hosting_python_app/login/

For admin path, instead to be:
https://subdomain.domain.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
it becomes:
https://subdomain.domain.com/home/user/a2hosting_python_app/admin/login/?next=/home/user/a2hosting_python_app/admin/

At this point, if I edit the *urls.py* removing the trailing slash:

```
    urlpatterns = [
       path('admin', admin.site.urls),
       path('login', dashboard, name="dashboard"),
   ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
   urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

the login URL shows correctly, but the admin URL won't.

I have no APPENDING_SLASH set in *settings.py*.

Does anyone know why Django behave like this? What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the A2Hosting support, I was able to solve the issue.

The problem was that, by following their [guide](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/python/installing-and-configuring-django-on-linux-shared-hosting), I set the variable SCRIPT_NAME (in *passenger_wsgi.py* file) to the unix path of the python app created in cPanel:

```
SCRIPT_NAME = '/home/a2hosting_user/a2hosting_python_app'
```

Setting this variable to an empty string, solved the problem:

```
SCRIPT_NAME = ''
```